# ASP.Net referencing an object in the site.master from inheriting page

Tags: asp.net

Is there a way to reference an object from the Site.Master page from the inheriting page?

In other words, the Site.Master contains an object RadComboBoxDepartment.  I want to reference it in the code behind of the page inheriting from Site.Master.

Answer (score 0):

Sure you can access your control in master page from the content page.

For example if you want to access the drop down list you can do it like this:

```
DropDownList dropDownFromMasterPage = (DropDownList)Master.FindControl("RadComboBoxDepartment");
```

And if you are using `AJAX` toolkit or `Telerik` Combo Box control, you can simply replace the type with that.

PS: Make sure your control has this attribute: `runat="server"`